# How to get start and end date from jQueryFullcalendar?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I need to know the start and end date in monthly and weekly view.

Is there a way to do this easily with the plugin?

Another question:
Is it possible to implement client side caching for this plugin so that it caches 12 months of events.

This way, when user goes back, I don'e have to go to the server to pull that data.

Thanks

Comment: Why would you need FullCalendar to provide you the start and end dates in the month/week? You can do that using the Date object anyway, right? Also, for caching, you could look into HTML sessionStorage - I don't think FC supports local caching.

Comment: I have requirements to bring back all events for all the days in the calendar. Without knowing the start and end date, I can't do it. I am not seeing any pattern on getting the dates.

Comment: `$('#calendar').fullCalendar('clientEvents')` should give you all the events in the calendar. Does that help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`View Object` has `start`, `end`, `visStart` and `visEnd` properties, so you can simply try:

```
viewDisplay: function(view) {
    alert('Visible start date ' + view.visStart);
}
```

Of course you can get whole `View Object` using jQuery:

```
$('#id_of_calendar_div').fullcalendar('getView')
```

or only specific property:

```
$('#id_of_calendar_div').fullcalendar('getView').visStart
```

Answer (score 1):

My answer was based on FullCalendar v2.3.2

```
var viewStartDate = getViewFormattedDate($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').start._d);
var viewEndDate = getViewFormattedDate($('#calendar').fullCalendar('getView').end._d);
console.log(viewStartDate+"---"+viewEndDate);
```

You will get the Date object, and you can convert it into which ever date format you want to.